# Twitter: platform migration. It will be disabled permanently on August 1, 2012

Tags: facebook, twitter, endpoint

I have been trying to connect my Facebook Page to my Twitter account along with my regular Facebook page.

It links to my regular page fine...but Everytime I check my Facebook Fanpage it gives me this error:

ERROR: This endpoint has been deprecated. To temporarily reenable it, you may disable the "august_2012" platform migration. It will be disabled permanently on August 1, 2012.

I'm not a programmer.  I have looked everywhere to try to "Diasable" this and cannot find where to do this.  When will this be fixed on Facebook/Twitter's end?

Comment: I think you misread that post, by disabled they mean no longer able to use. So the option you were looking for would not help you, since you technically want it enabled... 

And like the answer below says, it's now disabled permanently so there's not gonna be a fix since nothing is broken :P

Comment: This is something Twitter needs to fix - contact them

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this will never be fixed.
Facebook platform is a living environment - it means new stuff is added to it and some stuff is also removed. It seems the functionality has been removed. Since it is already past 1st August it is gone for good.